# How to insert record automatically in mongodb (nodejs, express, mongoose)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a team-based project. I created a new collection with some records (inserted manually). Is there any script or code to insert these records automatically from within the code, so that my when my colleague will work they do not need to insert those records again.

Code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ServiceCategoryTypeSchema = new Schema({
        _id: {type: String},
        name:String
    }, {
        collection:'service_category_type',
        timestamps:{createdAt:'created_at', updatedAt:'updated_at'}
    }
);


module.exports = {
    getModel: function(db){
        return db.model("ServiceCategoryType", ServiceCategoryTypeSchema)
    },
    schema:ServiceCategoryTypeSchema
};
```

This is the record, I am thinking to add automatically,

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Inventory", 
    "name" : "Inventory"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Non-inventory", 
    "name" : "Non-inventory"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Service", 
    "name" : "Service"
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your model in, say, `YourModel`, then you should be able to save your data that you have in, say, `yourData` with something like this:

```
new YourModel(yourData).save(function (error, data) {
   // handle errors, log success etc.
});
```

You can do it for as many pieces of data as you want.

When you populate the database with some data it may be a good idea to first check if the database is not populated yet.

### Example

Here is a working example program that saves such data - I changed the database and collection names so that you won't mess with your real database when you run it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var P = mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/poptest');

var TestModel = mongoose.model('TestModel', new Schema({
        _id: String,
        name: String
    }, {
        collection: 'testcollection',
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    }
));

var sampleData = [
    {_id: "Inventory", name: "Inventory"},
    {_id: "Non-inventory", name: "Non-inventory"},
    {_id: "Service", name: "Service"}
];

P.all(sampleData.map(i => new TestModel(i).save()))
    .then(() => console.log('Data saved'))
    .catch((err) => console.log('Error: ' + err))
    .finally(process.exit);
```

You need to install `mongoose` and `bluebird` for it to work:

```
npm i mongoose bluebird
```

It creates 3 documents in the `poptest` database on localhost. You can verify it by running:

```
mongo poptest
```

and querying the `testcollection` collection:

```
db.testcollection.find();
```

You should get something like:

```
> db.testcollection.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : "Inventory",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.374Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.374Z"),
    "name" : "Inventory",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "Non-inventory",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.377Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.377Z"),
    "name" : "Non-inventory",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "Service",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.377Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-14T16:13:37.377Z"),
    "name" : "Service",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rsp, i will definitely check your code. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6326

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test'
const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri)
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
})

const Test = db.model('test', testSchema)

const test = new Test({ name: 'Billy', age: 31 })

db.once('connected', function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  Test.create(test, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err) }
    console.log(doc)
    return db.close()
  }) 
})
```